Reasons why certain key changes work better than others
When a song has a key change, often towards the end, it goes up, rather than down. There is probably a reason for this.
Not asking about modulations, but actual key changes (tonicization), as in the last chorus moves up to another key.
Often that new key is one semitone, or one tone higher than the original. What's the reason for those particular changes, above any others?

Can you clarify what for you is the difference between a key change and a modulation?

@ToddWilcox - I'm regarding a modulation as a temporary key change, which won't last a chorus, whereas a key change will stay in the new key for the duration, and not return to the original. For example, song's in key E, then key changes up to, say, F for the last chorus. Not related to each other, musically.

Colloquially, I'd usually use "modulation" for any situation in which you move to a new key for a significant time (like through the end of the song, or until the next modulation). For shorter things, like just spending a couple of bars in "of V" stuff, I'd say that those bars "tonicize V." But esp in pop music, the "Mack-the-Knife" practice of hikin it all up a step, I would call modulation.

@AndyBonner - sounds like a question is heralded - what's the difference between key change and modulation?

@Tim That would be a largely hair-splitty one for me: "key change" is when the author bothers to change the key signature, while "modulation" is the process or mechanism of getting from one tonality into another. Or, reasonably, we could just say that "key change" can just be used interchangeably with "modulation."

@AndyBonner - Maybe it's all the poorly notated pieces I've already seen (and all the shifts to the relative major), but I'd say neither key changes nor modulations require key signature changes.

@Dekkadeci I mean, it's just a matter of convenience, right? A key signature doesn't "make a key" by itself, just shows it. We could write everything with no key signature and just throw around the flats and sharps, but we could still say that a song was "in the tonality of" G major. See all the questions here about what key signature to use with modes. So yeah, the decision whether or not to change the signature mostly has to do with how long you're going to stay there and whether it's "worth it."

@Tim Regarding your question in the comments, see the video "What's the Difference Between a Modulation and a Key Change?" for some opinions.

From a deleted answer: "The shift by a whole step up might be the most harmonious, because it's the key of a secondary dominant to the dominant"

In universities in the U.S., “modulation” means changing to a different key. Some key changes are brief and not considered modulations but might be described as tonicization. In jazz I’ve heard of “the key of the moment” because there may be multiple ii-V-I patterns across several related tonal centers in a single head and they don’t last long enough to analyze them as modulations.

One thing that happens briefly when a new major tonic chord is stated a whole step above the previous major tonic chord is there is a temporary sense of the Lydian mode (the third of the new tonic is the raised 4 of the old tonic). Whether it’s cultural or psychological, Lydian sounds have impact. This is also a feature of the applied/secondary dominant of the V chord.

@ToddWilcox - this is closer to my thinking. I'll add a 'theoretical' answer later.

Key changes upwards combine several emotional effects:

Before language existed, the ancestors of humans evolved communication via emotional expressions such as changes of the average pitch of grunts and shrieks and emotional reactions to them. Pitch changes remained a useful "paralanguage" also after language emerged. Music key changes upwards may partially activate brain pathways associated with this instinctive emotional response (alertness, excitement, ...) to raised pitch.

With more music-listening experience, emotional responses become more nuanced due to learned associations between music patterns and emotional context (such as correlating music patterns, lyrics, movie scenes).

Things are most interesting when they are neither too predictable nor completely chaotic, that's a variant of the Goldilocks principle. A key change may feel unusual because it deviates from the pattern of the music. It doesn't deviate too much if it maintains a similar pitch and song structure.


This video about unprepared key changes upwards states that such key changes feel "clichéd" (see #2 above) but also feel like "injecting new energy" (see #1 and #2) and "jarring" (see #1 and #3). Key changes by a semitone up, due to not sharing many notes between keys, are described as "noticeable" and particularly jarring, probably because the brain wasn't necessarily expecting so many new pitch classes at that moment. (Even if the listener already knows the song, the way it breaks the musical pattern may still evoke emotions.)
These key changes achieve certain effects, other key changes achieve a different effect, see videos about other kinds of key changes.

We are aware of what the key changes are supposed to do ( I don't absolutely subscribe to that, but that's not the issue). What I'm looking for is what musical mechanism, or why particular changes of key can happen 'seamlessly', as far as the notes/harmonies are concerned.

@Tim In many cases, they aren't seamless, quite the contrary, they are described as "jarring", and that's their intended effect.

That'll be the 'truck driver's gear change' you're talking about! But even some of those, suddenly going from one key to another, can sound good!

@Tim Are you asking for an interpretation of the harmony (and melody) across the key change? Harmony is different in different songs. You might want to post separate questions about specific songs or chord progressions, then separately ask for a meta-analysis of those analyses, if that's what you're looking for. What do you think?

I'm thinking specifically of, say, C>Csharp, or C>D, which both get used a lot. C>B doesn't seem to work, but apart from the lowering of the key, why not, key-wise?

@Tim Key changes downwards (for example by a semitone) do exist in popular songs, see this video from the same playlist. I was asking what you think about my comment regarding what you're looking for and every song being very different. Analyzing the many very different songs might go beyond the scope of just one question, and require several questions.

@Tim Wait, this isn't the answer you're looking for? You might edit to make that clear, but I think it's the best answer. That is, the answer to "why up rather than down" is not a music-theory reason but a performative and affective one: As things get higher (or faster) they get more exciting, or at least more expressive. Modulation downward would be no harder technically than upward.

@AndyBonner How it isn't music theory?

@user1079505 By which I mean, I think Tim is hoping for something like "modulation one step lower is harder than one step higher because [something about pivot chords or tonality or scales]." But I don't think there's something like that. The only reason upward is more common is because it's more "fun."

@AndyBonner isn't all music theory about explaining why some things sound more fun than the others?

@user1079505 Hehe, "what music theory is and what its for" is worthy of very long discussion, and has gotten a lot of it over the centuries. But the comments section under an answer isn't the place to tackle it. Hopefully you can understand my meaning: That as far as I know, there isn't a "reason involving chords n scales n stuff" that up is more common than down. Parsing the emotive and affective impact of musical gestures is arguably part of the broader field of musicology, especially is it will often venture into ethnomusicology.

The two first bullets in this answer contradict each other. Is is learned or is it instinctive?

@user1079505 An emotional response in many cases is influenced by instinct, past experiences (and how they were processed), and current mental state. It's not a contradiction, it's a combination of those factors.

Changing key up a perfect fifth (e.g. from C major to G major) mostly keeps the familiar set of tones.  Just one note in the set is sharpened (F to F#).  The difference is that this new note has a pitch/frequency 106% higher/greater; it has a little bit more energy.
If we go up a major second instead (C major to D major), there are two notes with more energy than before.  But more importantly, our old familiar tonic isn’t even in this new set of tones, it’s become sharper (C to C#).  And this note isn’t particularly stable in the new key either, it wants to move us up another half-step up to the new tonic.
When the whole key moves up a semitone (C major to C# major) every note in the scale becomes more energised  — I’m using the term energy in both a physics sense, but also in the sense that a DJ might.  This key change isn’t subtle.
Similarly, a key change: down perfect fifth (C major to F major), down a major second (C major to Bb major), or down a semitone (C major to Cb major) flattens notes in the set, and thus reduces one form of energy in the music.
Other key changes have more complicated things going on, and can be analysed/utilised in different ways.

I think @root's answer addresses the question of "why?" High pitch is psychologically associated with excitement. Modulating/transposing up is a fundamental of building excitement or tension which exploits that psychology. If you are looking for music theory to corroborate that, some things to consider:

General melodic contour. The common arch contour rises to a climax the descends to an end.
A root movement of an ascending perfect fifth is a fundamental "opening". It creates tension. It's the antecedent. A descending perfect fifth is the corresponding "closing"/resolution/consequent.
Melodic sequences upward create tension, downward release tension.
Modulating "up" to the dominant involves raising a pitch (subdominant is raised to become a new leading tone) and is part of "structural" tension usually as part of a build to a mid-point climax, modulating "down" to the subdominant involves lowering a pitch (the leading tone is lowered to become a new subdominant) and is often a post-climax denouement.

You might say that begs the question of why those upward movements are used to build tension and excitement. We then just get into a circular discussion going back to the point about pitch and psychological excitement. Perhaps you might ask why high pitch is associated with psychological excitement. And you could try shifting to physics and answer that higher pitch/fast frequencies have more energy, and the natural world tends to not expend energy unless compelled to. Think survival scenarios where things speed up, like running speed, heart rate, etc. and that's excitement. At a certain point I like to direct people to this interview with Richard Feynman. You should make the connection around :54 into the video, but watch from the beginning to understand what triggered Feynman.

When a song has a key change, often towards the end, it goes up, rather than down. There is probably a reason for this.

If yet another repeat of pop song chorus risks monotony, transposing up is a simple way to inject some excitement into the music. I supposed a shift downward could work too, but it makes sense to shift in a direction that fits the original mood of the song. An upbeat rock song would probably want to maintain not lessen the energy level. On the other hand, if the song were mellow, a shift down might be an effective way to extend an ending, a way to effect a denouement.

Often that new key is one semitone, or one tone higher than the original. What's the reason for those particular changes, above any others?

Vocal range must be a practical consideration when the shift is a literal transposition up.
You could make some comparisons between the common tones of the keys, but I think that doesn't matter. That is normally an aspect of "smooth" modulation where the supposed concern is to not notice the change. But in the case of adding excitement to a repetitious chorus the whole point is to notice the change, and hopefully react with excitement. Any more specific emotional reaction beyond a "refresh" or "excitement" probably will depend more upon the main content of the song that the size of the upward transposition.

In my opinion, and by my observation, a number of popular songs regularly heard on the radio employ a half-step up modulation as a clever songwriting device designed to either create a tension in the mind of the listener, or to offer an uplifting, gratifying ambience or mood.
George Benson's song, On Broadway, for instance.
Part of the way through the song, the key climbs from G# major to A major.
Smooth and interesting.
Michael Jackson, Man In The Mirror.
G major to A flat major
Right on the lyric, "CHANGE".
Brilliant.
Ain't No Mountain High Enough by Marvin Gaye.
Why does this work?
It just does.
From a psychological perspective, perhaps radio listeners find the modulation to be interesting. More interesting that formulamatic songs that offer nothing that turns their head.

I'm interested more in why it works, from a musical theory point of view. We know it does, but what is the mechanism that makes it work?

That's a fair question, Tim.
But when you are talking pure music theory, and all human emotions, likes, and dislikes are removed from the equation, you are left to ponder and perhaps reinterpret the word, "work".

Taking the examples in OP's last paragraph, I think the 'smoothness' (as opposed to the already mentioned truck driver's gear change) is related to pivot notes.
Let's take key C> key C♯. Tonic chord in C is, well, C:CEG. To get to key C♯, often the V of that new key is used - G♯7. Comprising G♯B♯D♯ and F♯. The common note ( pivot note) here is the C/B♯. Not only is it the tonic pitch of the old key, but the leading note of the new.So the transition is smooth.
Let's look at key C to key D. CEG goes to the V of key D, which comprises A C♯ E G. Thus two pivot notes, from the old key to the V of D. Again quite smooth.
There's the obvious changes key C>F and key C>G, with many common notes, but as far as songs are concerned, singing half an octave up or down from what happened in the previous chorus is often a bridge too far.

One reason modulations to dominant and subdominant are "smooth" is the way the leading tone/subdominant roles "flip". In functional terms their role as dominant chord tones does not change despite the actual pitch change. Ex. key change C to G, subdominant F becomes leading tone F#, either tone has an important role functioning in the respective dominant chords of the two keys. You could say while pitch changes, general function does not. Also, the two tonics of C and G maintain their roles as tonal scale degrees. Obviously, things change, but their is a kind of general unity maintained.

Key changes like C to C# or C to D aren't normally called smooth. Usually the explanation is about the number of changes between the key signatures. But you can also point out the functional scale degree changes. A C tonic changing to an enharmonic B# leading tone is a big functional change. That doesn't mean it can't "work." It just means "theoretically" a lot of things change. I think the various answers explain why it can work. The big change is dramatic and exciting. There are valid reason for either smooth or abrupt changes. They can all work for different reasons.

@Tim you argue that transition from C to C# is "smooth" because the dominant to C#, G#7 shares a tone with C. The same way you could use the note E as a pivot tone in C -> F#7 -> B, yet you say C->B doesn't work for you. Sorry, but this doesn't add up. Moreover, the key change you ask in the question very often occurs instantly, without a dominant modulation.

Yes, a 'truck driver's' key change, shifting wholesale into a final chorus, is typically up a semitone or up a tone. A slightly more sophisticated 'up a minor 3rd' is also reasonably common.
Why?  Well, you do it to give the song a boost, an 'upper'.   And going up is an upper!
Just now and again a song with a 'big ending' will actually be taken DOWN a key.  Usually, I think, to accommodate a particular singer who finds a song lies well for their voice in one particular key but wants to go for a higher 'money note' at the end.   Rather than lowering the whole song, they'll get the arranger to concoct a key shift DOWN for the last chorus, putting the high note into their vocal range, but to do it in a way that doesn't SOUND like a 'downer'.  A rising melody can disguise a downward modulation!  Clever.

Can't say I've ever played or listened to any song that mods down at the end (or anywhere). Any examples, please?
